# Fragments in a linear layout after configuration change

Tags: android, configuration, orientation, fragment

I have an activity that contains a linear layout and a fragment placeholder.

```
<RelativeLayout >

    <LinearLayout/>

    <fragment />

</RelativeLayout>
```

In onCreate() for the activity I place a fragment in the fragment placeholder and multiple fragments in the linear layout. This works fine until the phone goes through a configuration change (e.g. orientation change).

I do nothing special for an orientation or configuration change. What happens is really strange: the fragment placeholder is populated correctly but the linear layout now contains duplicate fragments. i.e. if the linear layout had `fragment1` and `fragment2` in it before, it will now show `fragment1 fragment2 fragment1 fragment2`. What is going on here?

As an additional note: I am using reflection to create the fragment objects, but I don't think that should change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The framework will automatically add the fragments to your view when the orientation is changed. Only execute the add fragment transactions when the paramBundle is null.

Example (using support library):

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle paramBundle) {
    super.onCreate(paramBundle);
    if (paramBundle == null) {
        FragmentManager localFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction localFragmentTransaction = localFragmentManager
                .beginTransaction();
        localFragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragmentHost,
                new MyFragment(), MY_FRAGMENT_TAG);
        localFragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that the "correct" way to handle this situation? It seems like a bit of a hack to me. And it doesn't fit in with how I thought activities and fragments operated during a configuration change. Why are the old fragments still in the layout? I thought they would have been destroyed. Thanks, Styx.

Comment: That is the way it is supposed.to be done.   The fragments aren't "still in the layout".  They were saved to the bundle to be recreated because of the orientation change (there's a reason it is called a savedinstancestate).

Comment: So the fragments that were created before the orientation change are actually referenced within the savedInstanceState bundle?

Comment: Yes. They are automatically recreated by the FragmentManager from the saved instance state.